# Android options menu button only works after second click

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, android-optionsmenu

I have the following code in my app. There is a login button which works fine on my view. I've overridden the optionsmenu on my view and placed the login code inside a listener attached to the optionsmenu. When i press the optionsmenu login button nothing happens on the first click, but everything works fine on subsequent clicks. Why is this?

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menuentryoptionsmenu, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {


        case R.id.login:
                        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener(){

                            @Override
                            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Log.e(TAG, "login clicked from opts menu");
                                 compId = "100";
                                    String theUsername = userName.getText().toString();
                                    thePassword = passwordPin.getText().toString();
                                    String loginType = "1";



                                    String[] params = new String[]{compId, theUsername, thePassword, loginType};

                                    //validate user Asynchonously on background thread
                                    AsyncValidateCarer avc = new AsyncValidateCarer();
                                    avc.execute(params);
                                return true;
                            }});


            return true;


        case R.id.changeuser:
            if(isAllowChangeUser.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
            item.setVisible(false);
            }
            return true;



        default:

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the click listener.
Just put the whole login code after the `case R.id.login:`.

That's because onOptionsItemSelected is already the click, you don't have to create and set it again.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the first time you click on the option menu item, you are only adding the OnMenuItemClickListener listener. The second time you click, you are triggering that listener.

Try removing the onMenuItemClickListener code and put the code in your onMenuItemClick function into the switch statement directly.